# How do I get my express server to recognize the sessions i'm setting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, express-session

I have been trying to get into node express and brushing up on my programming in order to try a personal project. I'm trying to get into sessions as a way to have a user be authenticated on a site. I can not for the life of me understand how I can get the backend server to recognize the authorized user and this is important for me as I want the backend to fetch from my database based on the session and perferably avoid sending post requests with username as they can be spoofed.

I have the following backend code:

```
// Setup express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");

//Setup mongodb
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const URI = "---xxx---";

mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useNewUrlParser:true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
});

const User = require("./models/user.model.js");


// creating 24 hours from milliseconds in order to set the maxAge of the cookie
const oneDay = 100*60*60*24;


//session middleware
app.use(
    session({
      secret: "somethingsecret",
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { maxAge: oneDay },
      resave: false,
    })
  );
  
  

//parsing the incoming data
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//serving public file
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// cookie parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"]
  }));
  

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    req.session.userid = "user1";
    console.log("Userid set: " + req.session.userid);
    res.send(req.session.userid);
});

app.get("/api/event", (req, res) => {
    console.log("Accessed /api/event");
    console.log("Userid: " + req.session.userid);
    res.send(req.session.userid);
  });
  

//Start the app / start listening on the specified PORT (Keep at the end of server code)
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running at port ${PORT}`));
```

Following frontned:

```
// Setup express
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 80;

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");

// creating 24 hours from milliseconds in order to set the maxAge of the cookie
const oneDay = 100*60*60*24;

//session middleware
app.use(session({
    secret: "somethingsecret",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {maxAge: oneDay},
    resave: false
}));


//parsing the incoming data
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

//serving public file
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// cookie parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    req.session.userid = "user1";
  
    if (req.session.userid) {
      res.redirect("event");
    } else {
      res.send("Frontend");
    }
  });
  

app.get("/event", (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.userid) {
        console.log(req.session.userid);
        res.sendFile('/views/event.html', {root:__dirname});
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

//Start the app / start listening on the specified PORT (Keep at the end of server code)
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running at port ${PORT}`));
```

And finally on a html page I have a script that runs on pageload to try to call the functions so that in the future i can populate the page.

```
// Create a session
fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Response:", response);
  return response.text(); // Read the response as text
}).then(function(data) {
  if (data) {
    try {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(data); // Attempt to parse the response as JSON
      console.log("Data:", jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Empty response");
  }
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Fetch Error:', err);
});

// Fetch the event data and fill out the fields
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/event", {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log("Response:", response);
  return response.text(); // Read the response as text
}).then(function(data) {
  if (data) {
    try {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(data); // Attempt to parse the response as JSON
      console.log("Data:", jsonData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error parsing JSON:", error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("Empty response");
  }
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Fetch Error:', err);
});
```

I have tried putting sessions on the frontend, backend, but whatever I do I can't get the backend to recognize the req.session.userid.

Comment: Maybe using a library like [passport](https://www.passportjs.org/) for your authentication can help.